# Advance search on Google Realtime API model binary files

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I have a web application where I bind Google Realtime API collaborative strings to UI components and get saved as binary files in Google Drive. I also have a need to create a custom search page where users can pick and choose to search against very specific set of collaborative strings in the files.

For example, if I have multiple collaborative strings saved in the model

```
...
model.getRoot().set('text1', someCollaborativeString1);
...
model.getRoot().set('text2', someCollaborativeString2);
...
model.getRoot().set('text3', someCollaborativeString3);
```

I want to be able to search files that contain a string in any set of those 3 collaborative strings as well as the title and description of the file.

All I found in Google's documentation is the following parameter in the query.

[image: Google's query documentation]

This tells me I cannot do my kind of advance search on the binary files. Is there a way to achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the IndexableText on the file in drive to the contents of your collaborative strings.  See https://developers.google.com/drive/web/file

Unfortunately you need to set this text manually, there is no streamlined way to automatically search over the contents.